# this is pointing to the quill editor toolbar

Tags: javascript, angular, quill

I use [Quilljs](https://quilljs.com/) for a textarea on my website. The standard editor don't support image upload to the server, so i have to implement a custom handler. In the documentation is written [the following:](https://quilljs.com/docs/modules/toolbar/#handlers)

> Handler functions will be bound to the toolbar (so using this will
>   refer to the toolbar instance) and passed the value attribute of the
>   input if the corresponding format is inactive, and false otherwise.

This is actually a problem for me and i dont know how to resolve it in a clean and "right" way. I built an angular application and i have written a custom handler for image uploading. This custom image handler should upload the image with the help of an angular service to the server. The data service is globally provided in the app and a member of my component and i can access it with `this.dataService`. But after clicking the image upload icon in the toolbar, `this` is bound to the toolbar, i can't access my data service anymore. Can i avoid this boundary to the toolbar?

In explicit. Assume i have created a quill editor with the following code:

```
this.editor = new Quill('#editor', {
      modules: { toolbar: "#toolbar"},
      placeholder: 'Some Placeholder',
      theme: 'snow'
});
```

Now i add a custom handler to the image icon with

```
this.editor.getModule("toolbar").addHandler("image", imageHandler);
```

and my handler function for instance:

```
imageHandler(event) {
  this.dataService.addImage(event.file);
}
```

which uses the dataService which i've already implemented and tested. But `this.dataService` don't exists because `this` is now bind to the toolbar. I initialized the service with the constructor of the component.

```
constructor(private dataService: DataService) {

}
```

When i call `this.dataService` in the constructor, then it can be found and the boundary is fine, but i need to call it in my image handler function to send the file to the server.

Best regards,
Sven

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to solve this problem is to change

```
this.editor.getModule("toolbar").addHandler("image", imageHandler);
```

into

```
this.editor.getModule("toolbar").addHandler("image", imageHandler.bind(this));
```

now you can access your components variables/members in your image handler function. The toolbar have not anymore the focus.